# How do I get N records before given one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I get N records before given one?

I have the following table structure:

```
Id, Message
1, John Doe
2, Jane Smith
3, Error
4, Jane Smith
5, Michael Pirs
7, Gabriel Angelos
8, Error
```

Is there a way to get the N records before each Error and join all such records?
So the expected result for the N =2 will be

```
1, John Doe
2, Jane Smith
5, Michael Pirs
7, Gabriel Angelos
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23589/1)

Comment: `select * from [tabl1] where Message <> 'Error'`

Comment: @Greg Only "N records before" !

Comment: Gets my upvote for being an interesting problem.  It would be even better with a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a row number column if your Ids do not increment without gaps.  Then you can use a simple join to find the previous N.  Your previous N could overlap... so you have to add `distinct` if you do not want duplicates.

```
declare @N as integer
set @N=2

;with cte_tbl (Id, Message, rownum) AS
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as rownum from test
)
select distinct Prev.Id, Prev.Message
from cte_tbl
join cte_tbl Prev
on Prev.rownum between cte_tbl.rownum-@N and cte_tbl.rownum-1
where cte_tbl.Message = 'Error'
    and Prev.Message <> 'Error'
order by Prev.Id
```

If the one of the previous `@N` records is an error, the 'error' record will NOT show up.  This would have to be modified if you do want those to be included.  Just simply remove the line `and Prev.Message <> 'Error'`.

Comment: @Doesn't really work. It doesn't filter out the errors if there are more than 8 rows. If there are subsequent rows with `Error` after the 8th, they will still be shown.

Comment: As I mentioned... it does not filter out the 'ERROR' records, the question did not specify so i did not filter them out.  If they need to be filtered out a simple addition to the where clause will remove them.

Comment: @Brans I updated the answer to exclude the records with 'Error' message.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `cross apply`.  The logic is a bit different from typical applications, because you only want the records from the `cross apply` subquery:

```
select t2.*
from table t cross apply
     (select top 2 t.*
      from table t2
      where t2.id < t.id
      order by t2.id desc
     ) t2
where t2.message = 'Error';
```

For those inclined, there is also a method using window functions, but it is a little more cumbersome.  Do a reverse cumulative sum of `Error` records to identify values before a given error.  Then enumerate these and choose the ones you want:

```
select t.id, t.message
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by grp order by id desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when message = 'Error' then 1 else 0 end) over
                       (order by id desc)) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
where seqnum between 2 and 3;
```

Note that the filter is between 2 and 3, because `'Error'` has a value of 1.

Comment: `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.` ? [**LINK here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fec8f/9)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu . . . *I* saw `top 2` when I looked at that.  Now everyone else will too.

Comment: As a note to anyone reading the answers, either of these answers should have better performance than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the rows that are 'Error' and join with id previous to it. Assuming your IDs are consecutive. If they aren't get a consecutive id with the help or ROW_NUMBER().

You can try this:

```
    select
    T.*
    from (
        select
            id iderror
        from myTable 
        where
            Message = 'Error'
    ) errorRows
    inner join myTable T on
        T.id between errorRows.iderror -2 and errorRows.iderror -1 and
        T.Message <> 'Error'
```

Comment: `Invalid column name 'errorRows'.` Are you actually referring to `iderror`?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu yes i am ... sorry

Answer (score 0):

This would be a little bit easier if you were using an identity field for ID, then you would have continuous numbers, but you can use this method. I am Ranking the rows and then returning the ones prior to the error.

```
select t1.Rank_ID, t1.id, t1.message, te.id
from (select rank() over(order by id) as Rank_ID, id, message from tbl_test) t1
inner join (select rank() over(order by id)as Rank_ID, id, message from tbl_test)  te
on t1.Rank_ID between te.Rank_ID-2 and te.Rank_ID-1
where te.message='Error'
```

Comment: Identity column doesn't guarantee *continuous* numbers. You shouldn't rely on them being ordered either. Just treat identity as autoid, and you'll save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: I understand that, I was just trying to get the point across that a continuous ID field would be nice as he was missing ID 6. This is why I used the 'RANK()'.